# Using VTD-XML with node.js

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, vtd-xml

VTD-XML looks like something a perfect solution to a problem I've had for a long time, random access to very large XML files (in my case MediaWiki dump files like those for Wiktionary).

The question is, is there a way to use VTD-XML from node.js? I can't find anybody mentioning the two topics together with my Internet searches.

VTD-XML is officially available for Java, C#, C++, and C. But no mention is made on their site about any scripting languages, including JavaScript and node.js.

Is there a solution I haven't found for using these together, or where should I start if I were to roll my own?

Answer (score 0):

Not at this time. Are you trying to process huge XML in a client's browser windows? Usually XML this size gets processed in a server environment, which is why so far it is only ported to popular server programming languages.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Node.js is a fairly new and very popular JavaScript based platform for the server side. I didn't really expect direct support for it from VTD-XML, but rather something like a C-to-node.js binding just like I would expect for any other scripting language like Perl, Python, Ruby, or PHP. Usually these are made by third party enthusiasts.